# Alerting if textboxes are empty

Tags: javascript, php

my form:

```
<form method="post" action="getQuote.php" onsubmit="check()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input id="idname" class="inputBox" name="name"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone Number:</td>
            <td>
                <input id="idphone" class="inputBox" name="phone" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Moving From:</td>
            <td>
                <input id="idfrom" class="inputBox" name="from" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Moving To:</td>
            <td>
                <input id="idto" class="inputBox" name="to" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date:</td>
            <td>
                <input id="iddate" class="inputBox" name="date" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td> &nbsp; </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button name="signup" class="myButton">
                <font style="color: #ffffff">Get A Quote</font>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

my script:

```
<script>
    function check() {
        var n = document.getElementById(idname);
        var p = document.getElementById(idphone);
        var f = document.getElementById(idfrom);
        var t = document.getElementById(idto);
        var d = document.getElementById(iddate);
        var test1 = n.length;
        var test2 = p.length;
        var test3 = f.length;
        var test4 = t.length;
        var test5 = d.length;
        alert(test1);
        alert(test2);
        alert(test3);
        alert(test4);
        alert(test5);
    }
</script>
```

i am calling the script as onsubmit function of the form, but the page is not showing the alert. in stead, it is going to the getQuote.php file. Can Anyone Tell me, what the problem is? i think, i am missing something silly.

N.B : i have not written the part to compare, if the value is empty or not. just checking the values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First add "" between variables name. 
    Example for checking empty values in javascript, 
    `var n = document.getElementById(idname); 
    if(n==''){
        alert ("Please fill idname");
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
   <script>
        function check() {
            var n = document.getElementById('idname');
            var p = document.getElementById('idphone');
            var f = document.getElementById('idfrom');
            var t = document.getElementById('idto');
            var d = document.getElementById('iddate');
            var test1 = n.length;
            var test2 = p.length;
            var test3 = f.length;
            var test4 = t.length;
            var test5 = d.length;
            alert(test1);
            alert(test2);
            alert(test3);
            alert(test4);
            alert(test5);

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The `onsubmit` handler needs to return `false` if you do not want it
   to continue submission of the form.
2. Be sure you are checking against the `value` attribute of each element you are checking.

**Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="getQuote.php" onsubmit="return check()">
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
  function check() {
    var n = document.getElementById(idname);
    var p = document.getElementById(idphone);
    var f = document.getElementById(idfrom);
    var t = document.getElementById(idto);
    var d = document.getElementById(iddate);
    var test1 = n.value.length;
    var test2 = p.value.length;
    var test3 = f.value.length;
    var test4 = t.value.length;
    var test5 = d.value.length;
    alert(test1);
    alert(test2);
    alert(test3);
    alert(test4);
    alert(test5);
    if (test1 == 0 || test2 == 0 || test3 == 0 || test4 == 0 || test5 == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make life a lot easier if you remove the IDs on the form controls and add a class to those that are required to have a value. Then you just loop over all the form controls and make sure any with a class of, say, "required", has a non–empty value, e.g.

```
// Helper
function hasClass(el, className) {
  var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + className + '(\\s|$)');
  return re.test(el.className);
}

function checkForm(form) {
  var control, controls = form.elements;
  var allowSubmit = true;

  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    control = controls[i];

    if (hasClass(control, 'required') && control.value == '') {
      alert('Control ' + control.name + ' is missing a value.');
      allowSubmit = false;
    }
  }
  return allowSubmit;
}
```

Now you can add as many controls as you want and just add the "required" class for those that must have a value. The above can be made more sophisticated when different types of controls are used.